# How do i set randomly generated points on a google maps map in flutter (while specifying distance)?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I am making a flutter app where I have google maps with your current location.

but my problem is that I have no idea how to put random markers on a google maps map.

so what I mean is that I have a text field where someone can type in his distance that he/she wants to walk or bike. and that my app makes a route with the end and start points the location where the person is at that moment. and what I cant seem to find on the internet is how to generate the points for the route that is the distance they enter in the text field.

any ideas?
please and thank you

Comment: Please post the code you've tried to solve the issue with random markers in Google Maps for Flutter. Follow the guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mabye you can take a look at this (this should work)

```
LatLng getRandomLocation(LatLng point, int radius) {
  //This is to generate 10 random points
  double x0 = point.latitude;
  double y0 = point.longitude;

  Random random = new Random();

  // Convert radius from meters to degrees
  double radiusInDegrees = radius / 111000;

  double u = random.nextDouble();
  double v = random.nextDouble();
  double w = radiusInDegrees * sqrt(u);
  double t = 2 * pi * v;
  double x = w * cos(t);
  double y = w * sin(t) * 1.75;

  // Adjust the x-coordinate for the shrinking of the east-west distances
  double new_x = x / sin(y0);

  double foundLatitude = new_x + x0;
  double foundLongitude = y + y0;
  LatLng randomLatLng = new LatLng(foundLatitude, foundLongitude);

  return randomLatLng;
}
```

Comment: for 200m radius I'm getting points 5,000,000 meters away.

Comment: This Logic not working correctly. I's getting random lat long more than given radius.